# Google App Engine "no module named requests" PyDev

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev

I downloaded and installed [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for Python 2.7. Using the shell I can make "import requests" and actually use it without problems.

Thing is that when running Google App Engine it can't find it and prompts the error:

ImportError: No module named requests

I'm using PyDev-Eclipse as IDE for my project and tried adding the path (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests) both in

Project > properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > External Libraries

and in

Window > preferences > Pydev -Interpreter > Libraries

and none worked! Still having the same issue when trying to run my GAE app

Anyone could help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any 3rd party lib you use must be physically included in your project and deployed to appengine.  This means it is not sufficient to just install with easy_install or pip

See the docs  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Pure_Python

Comment: Great! created a symbolic link in my project folder to the path mentioned above and works perfectly. Thanks for your help