# discord bot errors (500) every 14 min being hosted on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, discord, google-app-engine-python

I have a discord bot that is being hosted on Google App Engine. It will work and run, and then roughly every ~14 min, the bot goes offline, and I see these errors:
[image]

Upon further review of the error logs, this is the output:

logMessage: "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."
severity: "INFO"
time: "2021-10-03T16:29:18.831860Z"
}

1: {
logMessage: "The warmup request failed. Please check your warmup handler implementation and make sure it's working correctly."
severity: "INFO"
time: "2021-10-03T16:29:18.831862Z"
}

2: {
logMessage: "Process terminated because it failed to respond to the start request with an HTTP status code of 200-299 or 404."
severity: "ERROR"
time: "2021-10-03T16:29:18.831863Z"

My app.yaml file is as follows:

```
runtime: python38

instance_class: B1

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

entrypoint: python3 bot.py
```

I'm quite new to GCP and hosting web services, so I am quite lost. Any help here is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a url handler for `/_ah/start`. (Might as well also provide for `/_ah/stop` and `/_ah/warmup` too).  Those are calls GAE will make to start and stop your app.  They should return an http response of `200`.  Here is an example, in Flask:

```
@app.route('/_ah/start')
@app.route('/_ah/stop')
@app.route('/_ah/warmup')
def warmup():
    # Handle your warmup logic here, e.g. set up a database connection pool
    return '', 200, {}
```

**EDIT:**  Valid responses are `200`–`299` or `404`

Comment: The configuration said it used B1 instance class, I don't think it needs warm up again.

Comment: pardon my naivety, does this mean in my discord bot.py code, I have to include flask as well? what would be included in "warm up logic"?

Comment: No.  It just means you need a url handler that will serve a 200 whenever GAE hits those urls.

Comment: so i don't necessarily need to include any "warm up logic", all i need to do is return 200?

Comment: you can try creating a hardlink to the requests library : https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/quickstart Is this link helpful?

Comment: I've never created those handlers for my GAE apps (standard and flex) and haven't had any issues.

Comment: @gasefan Perhaps because, in your apps, those urls route somewhere automatically.  In the OP's case, those URLs are returning `500`s.  OP needs to make sure those URLs return valid responses (200–299 or 404).

Comment: Where do I place this URL? I'm not using flask or any web framework here. My entrypoint in my .yaml is bot.py... is that incorrect?

edit: did you reply to yourself? gasefan and GAEfan haha

Comment: @RyanTom can you refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976121/500-server-error-on-google-app-engine-no-clue-why Is it helpful?