# PyDev PDFMiner GAE: ImportError: No module named pdfminer.converter

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev, pdfminer

I work on GAE project in PyDev
I'd like to use the PDFminer library in order to convert a pdf file to a text file.

My problem is when i run the application it dosn't work and it displays this error message :
ImportError: No module named pdfminer.converter

I tested the same code in a normale python project and it works fine.
I used the same code in python console and it works too

I add the pdfminer folder to the python interpreter, i removed the interpreter and i add it again but i have always the same error.

Really i don't what i have to do, can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the PDFMiner is a third party library i copied the PDFMiner's files into the project and i works fine GAE don't import lib if isn't a pure python even if it exits in PYTHONPATH I found the solution in this post: [Google App Engine "no module named requests" PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960017/google-app-engine-no-module-named-requests-pydev)